# Get Model Object as Array in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a person model that contains more than object, how do i calling this model as array in another class?

If I declare like this, I can't get count for the array

```
let personArray = Person()

override func viewDidLoad() {
     let count = personArray.count >> crash
}
```

I need to list the person in the Table View so i need to get personArray.count

Appreciate any help..

Thanks

Comment: `Person()` is one object `let personArray = [Person]()` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html), `Person` Model should represents encapsulated data. If you want to set an array of persons, you should do this:

```
let personsArray = [Person]()
```

persons array should contains `Person()` objects. Now you can:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     let count = personsArray.count
}
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your personArray is a `Person` model object. Array should be in this way:

```
var personArray = [Person]()
```

Comment: It definitely nil. Because you even don't init it.